# Missing Operator syntax error in Access crosstab query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having trouble figuring out what my query is missing:

```
PARAMETERS StartDate DateTime;
SELECT Count(GRANTS.[Grant Identified]) AS [CountOfGrant Identified]
FROM GRANTS
WHERE GRANTS.[Grant Identified]=Yes AND (GRANTS.[Identified Date] >= StartDate)
PIVOT ((Year(GRANTS.[Identified Date])*12 + Format(GRANTS.[Identified Date], "mm")) - (Year(StartDate)*12 + Format(StartDate, "mm")) + 1)
IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

My mind has become numb looking at this and I've run through all the solutions I could find (which is usually a `’ != '` issue).

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you missing the quotes around `Yes`, as in `WHERE Grants.[Grant Identified] = 'Yes'`?

Comment: Nope, those quotes are not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIVOT clause tells us that you are trying to do a crosstab query, but you don't have a TRANSFORM clause. The general form of a crosstab query in Access SQL is

```
TRANSFORM AggregateFunction(ValueField) AS whatever
SELECT RowHeadingFields
FROM TableName
GROUP BY RowHeadingFields
PIVOT ColumnHeadingField [IN (ValueList)]
```

so your query needs to look more like this:

```
PARAMETERS StartDate DateTime;
TRANSFORM Count(GRANTS.[Grant Identified]) AS [CountOfGrant Identified]
SELECT GRANTS.[Grant Identified]
FROM GRANTS
WHERE GRANTS.[Grant Identified]=Yes AND (GRANTS.[Identified Date] >= StartDate)
GROUP BY GRANTS.[Grant Identified]
PIVOT ((Year(GRANTS.[Identified Date])*12 + Format(GRANTS.[Identified Date], "mm")) - (Year(StartDate)*12 + Format(StartDate, "mm")) + 1)
IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was following another website as a guide and didn't think that part was necessary because I had already selected the Identified Count.